# Multimonitor menu bar

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, multiple-monitors, menu

Does anyone know of a way of extending the menu bar from one screen all the way across to the other, so that the gnome menu bar spans both/all monitors?

I'm basically looking for something similiar to MultiMon for linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using "Classic GNOME" (i.e., not Unity), right-click on one of your existing panels, and choose "New Panel". That should give you a funny-looking vertical panel on the side of one of your monitors. Right-click that new panel, and un-check the box that says "expand". You will then have a small little panel with a handle on it, under orientation, choose bottom (or top, wherever you want it) and it should now be a small horizontal panel floating on your screen. Move it where you want it, and check expand again and it will be locked in place. Right click on the panel and choose "add to panel", and choose "Window List". I'm assuming since you said you wanted something like MultiMon for Linux you wanted a task lisk of the apps/windows open on each screen, for that screen. This should be what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Super thanks for your help. Now if I can only figure out how to get monitor switching. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by monitor switching?

Comment: Ideally I'd be able to switch an application running on monitor 1 to monitor 2 with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Hmmm - that really seems doable. I don't have a dual-head machine running classic GNOME any more- I'm running 11.10 now (with Unity). But I think that might be something you could do with Compiz (if you have desktop effects enabled). Perhaps install 'ccsm' and tinker around in there...or post a separate question here, I'm sure someone would know.

Comment: This worked exactly as described.  I'm on 12.04.  Thanks!